# amazon web service and hosting on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, servlets, hosting, webserver, cloud

I am developing a web app and now I am looking for hosting solution. I am using java/servlets and my sql at the back end and I wanna create a instance of ubuntu 10.10 on amazon EC2 servers and host my app.
I chose amazon Ec2 because my web app is likely to use amazon simple mailing service, that becomes quite efficient.

My question is how do I host it on ubuntu and how do I config the ubuntu instance. What is the best web server which runs java/servlet? I am using mysql 5.1 at the back end.

I am integrating Amazon SMS with my web app, so how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeevan,

I would recommend that you take the simplest, cleanest Ubuntu EBS instance that you can find, and install whatever you need on it.

Once you are done installing and verifying that you have the right solution, go to the management console, right-click on the instance, and select the option to create an EBS image. This will enable you to go back to point zero if something goes wrong, and to deploy additional instances of the same kind if you need it later on.

Good luck!
Dotan